# Getting a Text out of a Div Block without using Regex?

Tags: javascript, parsing, text, userscripts

I want to get a certain Text out of a HTML document with a userscript. The interesting HTML part looks like this:

```
<div class="cartbox">
<strong>Fruits - Apple</strong><br>
<strong><font color="black">Color- Red</font></strong>
<br>
<strong><font color="black">Location - Shop2</strong>
```

I did isolate the class via `document.getElementsByClassName("cartbox")`and I tried to isolate the textcontent via `document.getElementsByClassName("cartbox")[0].textContent`, turn it into a String and use `indexOf(x) > -1)` to see if "Apple" is a substring of the given string x, but it doesn't work like I was hoping for.

Any ideas how I can check if there are Apples in the cartbox, without the usage of Regex?

Comment: What are you hoping `indexOf()` will do?

Comment: I'm hoping it is > than -1, to make sure the substring is existing in the bigger string.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into JSFiddle and it worked for me.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0moLjj0f/)

```
<div class="cartbox">
<strong>Fruits - Apple</strong><br>
<strong><font color="black">Color- Red</font></strong>
<br>
<strong><font color="black">Location - Shop2</strong>
```

`document.getElementsByClassName("cartbox")[0].textContent.indexOf('Apple');`

Of course this will only work for the first cartbox element.

Comment: Yeah, it works for real, no idea why it didn't work in my local implementation. Now it works as well.

Anyway, do you have a  good idea how to isolate only the word apple from the big string without using Regex? To make it dynamic and work for other type of fruits as well, so to speak.